# Drag event for fullcalendar version 2 in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, fullcalendar

Iam using Fullcalendar - JavaScript Event Calendar (jQuery plugin) in my project. Everything works fine in desktop. A user can add an event by dragging mouse  in `agendaweek view` and `agendaday view`.

How can i add the same functionality in ipad so that on selecting from one point to another i should be able to add an event in my fullcalendar from that time to the selected end time.How can i trigger the same event that works fine while dragging in desktop to the touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

I used, and it works for moving events (not sure it will work for what you are trying to do) is this: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch

then on the eventRender in fullCalendar you need to add $(element).addTouch();